mqtt publishing within on_message
i have a subscriver which gets fast message (like 500 milisecond per message). after getting message i do some calculation and and then publish the result again to another topic. The problem is, sometimes the publish is not successful (also unreliable). so i increased the qos to 1 and now it seems reliable (still have to test more). Here is my current code:
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient
import json

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc == 0:
        client.subscribe("xdk")
        print("Connected to broker")

    else:
        print("Connected failed")

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    global clientPub
    m = message.payload
    
    #do some calculation 

    obj = {"sensor": "primary", "counter": counter}
    clientPub.publish("primary_state", json.dumps(obj).encode('utf-8'),qos=1)
   

clientPub = mqttClient.Client("clientPUB_test",clean_session=True)
clientPub.connect("localhost", 1883,60)
clientPub.loop_start()

Connected = False
broker_address = "localhost"
port = 1883
client = mqttClient.Client("clientSUB_test", clean_session=True)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(broker_address, port, 60)
client.loop_start()


try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(.5)
except Exception as e:
    client.loop_stop()
    clientPub.loop_stop()
    client.disconnect()
    clientPub.disconnect()

Now, my questions are:

since I ma using loop_start() for both subscriber and publisher, that creates 2 different thread and if so delay in publishing should not have effect on subscriber message receiving. right?
If it is not that case, then the on_message will wait in publishing (since qos 1) and when it get the PUBREC, it starts consuming again. right? And in that case, some messages will be lost or it will be saved in the buffer (depending on qos). right?
Last question is, in this use case, would the async mqtt libraries be helpful ?


Calling publish causes the message to be queued and the function then returns (the message is actually sent by the network loop). If you want to wait for the PUBACK (PUBREC is only relevant at QOS2) then you need to use wait_for_publish() (see this example). As such, I think your questions are based upon a misunderstanding?

if publish() does not send message but it just queues the message in the buffer, then should i use loop_start and loop_end in the on_message() ?
my understanding was, i thought when i use loop_start(), outside the on_message() and then use publish() in on_message(), the publish() will put the message in the buffer and the background thread (started by loop_start()) will free the buffer in a regular interval. isn't that is the case?

loop_start "runs a thread in the background to call loop() automatically". So no, just call this once after connecting and the loop will be run in the background (sending/receiving messages). Do note that callbacks (e.g. on_message) will be called fron the thread the network loop is running in, and a long running callback function will block the loop (so if "do some calculation" takes a long time, then consider running it in another thread).
